# Why the tests are not running in Parallel mode using Selenium C# Unit?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, parallel-execution

I am trying to run my tests on Parallel mode but it is running sequentially and not parallelly. I found one question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61664038/selenium-c-sharp-nunit-3-12-0-is-not-running-tests-in-parallel) here but the solution provided in the same(Neil and Charlie, both) is also not working for me.

Here is my base class:-

```
[TestFixtureSource(typeof(TestDataProvider), nameof(TestDataProvider.BrowsersToRunWith))]
[TestFixture]
public class CrossBrowser
{
    public IWebDriver driver;
    public string Browsername { get; }


    public CrossBrowser(string browserName)
    {
        Browsername = browserName;

    }

    [SetUp]
    public void LaunchBrowser()
    {


        if (Browsername.ToLower().Contains("chrome"))
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

    }
```

TestDataProvider Class:-

```
class TestDataProvider
{
    internal static IEnumerable BrowsersToRunWith
    {            
        get
        {
           String[] browser = { "Chrome", "FireFox" };
            foreach (string b in browser)
            {
                yield return b;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class1:-

```
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)
public class UT1 : CrossBrowser
{
    
    public UT1(String browserName) : base(browserName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Browser is " + browserName);
    }

    [Test]
    public void OpenGoogle()
    {
        driver.Url = "http://google.com";
        driver.Quit();
    }
        
}
```

Test Class2:-

```
[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]

public class UT2 : CrossBrowser
{
    
    public UT2(String browserName) : base(browserName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Browser is " + browserName);
    }

    [Test]
    public void OpenGoogle()
    {
        driver.Url = "http://google.com";
        driver.Quit();
    }
        
}
```

Test Explorer:-

[image]

When I am running all the tests, it is running one by one and not on a parallel mode. Am I missing anything? Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: What did you try from that link ?

Comment: I was trying to do parallel execution on a Single class first but as mentioned in that link "Unit tests will not run in parallel if they are in the same class. If you have 3 separate test classes, it should work.". I created 2 different class and then tried but still the same issue.

Comment: So, you read Neil's one line answer, it didn't work out.. You then returned to the question and read Charlie's massive and in-depth answer that started out with "Neil's answer is wrong.." and decided to read more closely what Charlie had to say?

Comment: Apologies for not checking that solution as it was not marked as Answered but after you pointed it out, I tried those combinations as well. It's not working for me as well. I have one Fixture in the base class and in the child class, I have mentioned as Parallelscope.Self. I tried adding Parallelscrope.Children in the Base class as well but it also is not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code as plain text.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - done. Just kept the Test Explorer as an image. Please let me know if you need any more information.